# Hide Virtual function In Inherited Class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a class that inherits from `LinkButton` and I want to hide `OnClinentClick` from my class.

Somthing like this :

```
public class MyClass : LinkButton
{
    // some Code
}
```

And somewhere in code:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
MyClass.OnClinentClick = "";//this line must not be accessable
```

Comment: What is exactly "not accessible"? Should not compile, or should throw an exception at runtime? The former is not possible.

Comment: @Vlad : not visible. like private methods.

Comment: Well, this is not possible, because the base class method will still be visible. Because `MyClass` _is a_ `LinkButton`, so whatever is allowed with `LinkButton`, must be allowed with `MyClass` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hiding something from a class definition is not directly supported as it breaks OOP principles.

You could use the `new` operator, however, I wouldn't advise it. Personally, I would think about my design and/or use a `NotSupportedException` if there is no other way around it.

Comment: I don't think `NotImplementedException` is the right choice. IMO it should be `NotSupportedException`. Not implemented is for when you just haven't written the code yet.

Comment: @Femaref : what about Obsolete Attribute ?

Comment: In the right case? yes. In this case? No. Think about your design, trying to hide something when inheriting is code smell.

Comment: @Femaref : i think the Obsolete Attribute is a better choice.

Comment: @Raika: Except that it's not obsolete. The word "obsolete" doesn't mean "not used in this implementation".

Comment: @Cody Gray : i know. you have better Idea?

Comment: @Raika: Option 1 is inherit from a different base class. Option 2 is use composition, rather than inheritance. Option 3 (and this is a poor one) is hiding the method from IntelliSense and throwing a `NotSupportedException` when someone tries to access the method anyway. This is a particularly poor option because the flaw is discoverable only at run-time, and you'll still see the method show up on IntelliSense if you cast to the base class. The point everyone is trying to make is that inheritance implies an **is-a** relationship. All birds have wings. Dogs can't inherit from the Bird class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`EditorBrowsableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx)  to prevent it from being suggested by IntelliSense, but you can't get rid of it entirely.

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public virtual string OnClientClick { get; set; }
```

C# only supports public inheritance. You shouldn't be inheriting from a class whose methods don't make sense for all derived classes. Consider **composition** instead of inheritance to solve this problem.

Comment: Why C++, C#, disallow hiding of virtual functions

Answer (score 0):

You can override the function (that is, replace the base implementation with your one, as long as the former is virtual), but you cannot completely prevent the clients from calling the base class function if you hide it with `new`, as they may always cast to the base class.

Update:
actually, you cannot change the access from public to protected/private when overriding, this won't compile (http://ideone.com/Y65Uh). Besides that, if you use `new` to hide the base function and make it uncallable, the original function is still visible (http://ideone.com/xiL2F). If you declare the new function public (which is perhaps not what you want), the old function can still be called by casting to the base class (http://ideone.com/A3Bji).

Comment: **private new string OnClientClick {get;set;}** doesn't work. i try it by when i click **Go To Defination** in VS it goes to LinkButton OnClientClick.

Comment: @Raika: that is because the base function is still visible. You can only override the base class' function, not "cancel" it.

Answer (score -1):

How about making giving it a lower visibility. One of `protected` and `internal` might be what you want. Of course that doesn't remove such a member from the derived class, but just removes them from the public interface. It also requires control over the base-class. No idea if `LinkButton` is one of your classes.

You could also hide the property by reintroducing a new one with the same. But that's a bad idea, and casting back to the base-class allows outsiders to access it.

And you should consider using a has-a relationship instead of an is-a. i.e. Don't derive from a base class if you don't want all its public members. This violates OOP principles such as that it should be possible to substitute the derived class where the base class is expected.

You could also override it, and make the setter throw a `NotSupportedException`. But that's ugly too because it will only show an error at runtime instead of compiletime. You can generate compile-time warnings with attributes such as the `ObsoleteAttribute`.

Comment: Still will get error `cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member`

Comment: He obviously needs to do that when declaring the base-class, provided it's owned by him.

Comment: He Can hide only MyClass  implementation if make `private new` but base OnClinentClick  will still be accesible

Comment: I clearly wrote that hiding doesn't prevent access and is a bad idea. And you can't hide with `private` but need `public`. I think you can use a public property and decorate it with attributes to hide it from intellisense.

Comment: @CodeInChaos : looks like it's impossible.

Comment: Fully removing is impossible yes. But there are some tricks to partially hide it. But IMO the correct choice is refactoring the base-class.